# How do I pass variable or query to a python script using php via an ajax call?

Tags: javascript, python, php, jquery, ajax

I have A python Script Which Take Parameter or Sql query from the php file which I am running by call an ajax function. I have added the code for the php and ajax call. I have created a variable action for checking different cases. Here I am able to execute action = 1. but I am having issues calling action = 2 and 3.

Please Help Me by correcting what am i doing wrong and I would appreciate if someone can tell me a way where I can directly pass variables or parameter to a python via jquery or ajax.

```js
//ON LIVE DATA YOU CAN USE THE VALUE OF FILTERS USING THE AJAX CALL IN YOUR PYTHON SCRIPT  
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    var action = 1;

    $.ajax({
            
        url: 'http://localhost/plc_table_test/php/export/statistic.php',

        type: 'post',
        
        data:{
            
            action:action,
            
        },
                    
        success: function(data){
            
            $('.graphSummary').html(data);
            
        },  
        
    }); 
            
    
})

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#filter_graph_by_date').click(function(){ 
        
        $('.graphSummary').html('');
                      
        var from_date =$('#start_date').val();

        var to_date =$('#end_date').val();
                    
        var customer =$('#customer_filters').val();
                            
        var machine =$('#machine_filters').val();
         
        var cytype = $('#cyType_filters').val();

        var cystatus = $('#cyStatus_filters').val(); 
            
        var net = $('#ByNetWts').val(); 

        var res = $('#ByResWts').val();
        
        var action = 3;
                      
        if(from_date != '' && to_date != ''){
          
            $.ajax({
            
                url: 'http://localhost/plc_table_test/php/export/statistic.php',
               
                dataType: 'json',
                
                type: 'post',
                
                contentType: 'application/json',
                
                data:{ 
                    
                    from_date: from_date, 

                    to_date: to_date,
                                
                    customer: customer, 
                    
                    machine: machine,

                    cytype: cytype, 

                    cystatus: cystatus,
                    
                    net:net,
                    
                    res:res,
                    
                    action:action,
                },
                
                success: function(data){
                    
                    alert('Called option 3')
            
                    $('.graphSummary').html(data);
            
                },
                error: function(data){
                    
                    alert('Error Called option 3')
                    console.log(data)
            
                    $('.graphSummary').html(data);
            
                },
            });            

        }
        
    })
    
})


$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#filter_graph').click(function(){
        
        $('.graphSummary').html('');
                              
        var customer =$('#customer_filters').val();
                            
        var machine =$('#machine_filters').val();
         
        var cytype = $('#cyType_filters').val();

        var cystatus = $('#cyStatus_filters').val(); 
            
        var net = $('#ByNetWts').val(); 

        var res = $('#ByResWts').val();
        
        var action = 2;
         
        $.ajax({
            
            url: 'http://localhost/plc_table_test/php/export/statistic.php',
              
            type: 'post',
               
            data: { 
                    
                                
                customer: customer, 
                        
                machine: machine,

                cytype: cytype, 

                cystatus: cystatus,
                        
                net:net,
                    
                res:res,
                
                action:action,
            
            },
                
            processData: false,
                
            success: function(data){
            
                $('.graphSummary').html(data);
            
            }, 
        
        });            
  
    })
    
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php

$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=plcproject", "root", "");

$output = '';

if(isset( $_POST['action']))
{
   
if($_POST['action'] == '1'){
  
    $command = escapeshellcmd('C:/xampp/htdocs/plc_table_test/lib/graph_tables.py');

    $data = shell_exec($command);
    
    $query = "
        SELECT * FROM `statistics` WHERE id!= 1
        ";

    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);

    $statement->execute();

    $result = $statement->fetchAll();

    $total_row = $statement->rowCount();


    $sql = "";


    $sql = "
        SELECT * FROM `statistics` WHERE id = 1;
        ";

    $statement = $connect->prepare($sql);

    $statement->execute();

    $results = $statement->fetchAll();

    $total_rows = $statement->rowCount();



    $output .= '  
    <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered table-hover scroll" id="graph_summary">  
    <thead class="thead-dark">
    ';  


    if($total_rows > 0)
    {

        foreach($results as $row)

        {
            $output .= '
            <tr>
            <th width ="20">'.$row["a"].'</th>
            <th width="10%">'.$row["b"].'</th>
            <th width="10%">'.$row["c"].'</th>
            <th width="10%">'.$row["d"].'</th>
            <th width="10%">'.$row["e"].'</th>
            <th width="10%">'.$row["f"].'</th>
            <th width="10%">'.$row["g"].'</th>
            <th width="10%">'.$row["h"].'</th>
            <th width="10%">'.$row["i"].'</th>
            <th width="10%">'.$row["j"].'</th>
            <th width="10%">'.$row["k"].'</th>
            <th width="10%">'.$row["l"].'</th>
            <th width="10%">'.$row["m"].'</th>

            </tr>
            ';
        }

    }



    $output .= '
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    '; 


    if($total_row > 0)
    {

        foreach($result as $row)

        {
            $output .= '
            <tr>
            <td>'.$row["a"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["b"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["c"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["d"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["e"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["f"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["g"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["h"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["i"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["j"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["k"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["l"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["m"].'</td>
            </tr>
            ';

        }

    }

    $output .= '

    </tbody>   
    <table>

    ';
    
}

if($_POST['action'] == '2'){
    
    $customer = $_POST['customer']; 
    $machine = $_POST['machine'];
    $cytype = $_POST['cytype'];
    $cystatus = $_POST['cystatus'];          
    $net = $_POST['net'];         
    $res = $_POST['res'];          
    
  
    
    #$command = escapeshellcmd('C:/xampp/htdocs/plc_table_test/statistics.py');
    $new_sql = ''; #TBD
    $command = escapeshellcmd('C:/xampp/htdocs/plc_table_test/lib/graph_tables.py .$new_sql');

    $data = shell_exec($command);


    
    $query = "
        SELECT * FROM `statistics` WHERE id!= 1
        ";

    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);

    $statement->execute();

    $result = $statement->fetchAll();

    $total_row = $statement->rowCount();


    $sql = "";


    $sql = "
        SELECT * FROM `statistics` WHERE id = 1;
        ";

    $statement = $connect->prepare($sql);

    $statement->execute();

    $results = $statement->fetchAll();

    $total_rows = $statement->rowCount();



    $output .= '  
    <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered table-hover scroll" id="graph_summary">  
    <thead class="thead-dark">
    ';  


    if($total_rows > 0)
    {

        foreach($results as $row)

        {
            $output .= '
            <tr>
            <th width ="20">'.$row["a"].'</th>
            <th width="10%">'.$row["b"].'</th>
            <th width="10%">'.$row["c"].'</th>
            <th width="10%">'.$row["d"].'</th>
            <th width="10%">'.$row["e"].'</th>
            <th width="10%">'.$row["f"].'</th>
            <th width="10%">'.$row["g"].'</th>
            <th width="10%">'.$row["h"].'</th>
            <th width="10%">'.$row["i"].'</th>
            <th width="10%">'.$row["j"].'</th>
            <th width="10%">'.$row["k"].'</th>
            <th width="10%">'.$row["l"].'</th>
            <th width="10%">'.$row["m"].'</th>

            </tr>
            ';
        }

    }



    $output .= '
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    '; 


    if($total_row > 0)
    {

        foreach($result as $row)

        {
            $output .= '
            <tr>
            <td>'.$row["a"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["b"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["c"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["d"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["e"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["f"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["g"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["h"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["i"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["j"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["k"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["l"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["m"].'</td>
            </tr>
            ';

        }

    }

    $output .= '

    </tbody>   
    <table>

    ';

}

if($_POST['action'] == '3'){
    
    $from_date = $_POST['from_date'];
    $to_date = $_POST['to_date'];
    $customer = $_POST['customer']; 
    $machine = $_POST['machine'];
    $cytype = $_POST['cytype'];
    $cystatus = $_POST['cystatus'];          
    $net = $_POST['net'];         
    $res = $_POST['res'];
    
    $new_sql = ''; #TBD
    #$command = escapeshellcmd('C:/xampp/htdocs/plc_table_test/statistics.py .$from_date .$to_date .$customer .$res .$net .$cystatus .$cytype .$machine');

    $command = escapeshellcmd('C:/xampp/htdocs/plc_table_test/lib/graph_tables.py .$new_sql');
    
    $data = shell_exec($command);
    
    $query = "
        SELECT * FROM `statistics` WHERE id!= 1
        ";

    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);

    $statement->execute();

    $result = $statement->fetchAll();

    $total_row = $statement->rowCount();


    $sql = "";


    $sql = "
        SELECT * FROM `statistics` WHERE id = 1;
        ";

    $statement = $connect->prepare($sql);

    $statement->execute();

    $results = $statement->fetchAll();

    $total_rows = $statement->rowCount();



    $output .= '  
    <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered table-hover scroll" id="graph_summary">  
    <thead class="thead-dark">
    ';  


    if($total_rows > 0)
    {

        foreach($results as $row)

        {
            $output .= '
            <tr>
            <th width ="20">'.$row["a"].'</th>
            <th width="10%">'.$row["b"].'</th>
            <th width="10%">'.$row["c"].'</th>
            <th width="10%">'.$row["d"].'</th>
            <th width="10%">'.$row["e"].'</th>
            <th width="10%">'.$row["f"].'</th>
            <th width="10%">'.$row["g"].'</th>
            <th width="10%">'.$row["h"].'</th>
            <th width="10%">'.$row["i"].'</th>
            <th width="10%">'.$row["j"].'</th>
            <th width="10%">'.$row["k"].'</th>
            <th width="10%">'.$row["l"].'</th>
            <th width="10%">'.$row["m"].'</th>

            </tr>
            ';
        }

    }



    $output .= '
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    '; 


    if($total_row > 0)
    {

        foreach($result as $row)

        {
            $output .= '
            <tr>
            <td>'.$row["a"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["b"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["c"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["d"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["e"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["f"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["g"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["h"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["i"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["j"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["k"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["l"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["m"].'</td>
            </tr>
            ';

        }

    }

    $output .= '

    </tbody>   
    <table>

    ';
    
}
  
}



echo $output;





?>
```

Comment: why not just install python into your webserver and call it directly? (You could even make a HTTP request to it from the PHP, so you don't have to re-write the rest of the PHP in python too. The PHP would effectively be a proxy to the python, plus some extra functionality. Either way it would be better than this clumsy shell integration).

Answer (score 0):

You weren't specific what "troubles" you're having, but I can certainly see one issue which has nothing to do with python directly, and everything to do with string interpolation (or lack of it) in PHP, but which will likely make your python command invalid.

In PHP, variables inside a string are only converted into values if the string is double-quoted. In single-quoted strings, they are treated as literal values. See [the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) for more information.

So

```
'C:/xampp/htdocs/plc_table_test/lib/graph_tables.py .$new_sql'
```

for example, needs to be either:

```
"C:/xampp/htdocs/plc_table_test/lib/graph_tables.py .$new_sql"
```

or (if you prefer single-quotes for some reason):

```
'C:/xampp/htdocs/plc_table_test/lib/graph_tables.py .'.$new_sql
```

(I'm assuming the `.` is meant to be part of the shell command, and not PHP's string-concatentation operator. But if that's wrong, please remove it before using my examples.)